# Работа со словарями в шаблонах Django

Tags: python, django

Есть некоторая модель таблицы в Django, привязывающаяся к другой модели. Выглядит следующим образом:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    """
    Модель, к которой привязываются таблицы
    """
    pass

class Table(models.Model):
    """
    Модель таблицы
    """
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    """
    Функция, к которой позже ещё вернусь, с ней и будет связана проблема
    """
    def toDictTable(self):
        rows = list(self.tablerow_set.all())
        cols = list(self.tablecol_set.all())
        matrix = {
            row.id: {
                col.id: col.tablevalue_set.filter(row=row.id)
                for col in cols
            } for row in rows
        }
        return matrix


class TableRow(models.Model):
    """
    Модель строки таблицы
    """
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class TableCol(models.Model):
    """
    Модель столбца таблицы
    """
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class TableValue(models.Model):
    """
    Клетка таблицы, которая привязывается к столбцу и строке
    """
    col = models.ForeignKey(TableCol, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    row = models.ForeignKey(TableRow, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'["{self.col}"; "{self.row}"]: {self.value}'
```

Соответственно, эту таблицу нужно вывести через шаблонизатор Django.
Функцию `toDictTable` я и писал, собственно, для того, чтобы можно было в табличном виде вывести все значения таблицы.

Для того, чтобы вывести значения таблицы, я хочу использовать такой шаблон:

```
{% for table in item.table_set.all %}
<h4>{{table.title}}</h4>
<div class="table-scroll">
  <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th><span></span></th>
    {% for col in table.tablecol_set.all %}
    <th><span>{{col.title}}</span></th>{% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% for row in table.toDictTable %}
    <th><span>{{table.tablerow_set.all.row.id}}</span></th>
    {% for col in table.tablecol_set.all %}
      {% if col.id in table.toDictTable.row %}
        <td><span>{{table.toDictTable.row.col}}</span></td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Но есть проблема. В данном случае `row` и `col` - объекты соответствующих моделей, в то время как ключами словаря, который возвращает `toDictTable`, являются `id` этих объектов.

По факту мне нужно сделать что-то вроде `table.toDictTable()[row.id][col.id]`, но в том виде, как ключи записываются в Django-шаблонах (`table.toDictTable.row.id.col.id`) их, разумеется, реализовать не получится.

Какие есть способы решения этой... Заминки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется у тебя два варианта:

1. во view полностью подготовить список таблиц в удобном тебе формате и передавать их в шаблон, что бы цикл был не по `item.table_set.all` а по заранее подготовленным данным
2. вариант написать свой template tag, который будет выдавать нужную тебе информацию по заданным параметрам (подробней https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь 